# Spring Cloud: enabling SSL for Zuul and Eureka，How can store keystore.jks in git with spring cloud config server?

Tags: keystore, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

Spring Cloud: enabling SSL for Zuul and Eureka，How can store keystore.jks in git with spring cloud config server?

Answer (score 1):

We enabled SSL by configuring Bean that returns EmbeddedServletContainerFactory. 
Code snippet below -

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    Connector connector = new Connector();
Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setPort(port);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(Property from GIT);
        protocol.setKeystorePass(keyStorePass);
        protocol.setKeyPass(Property from GIT);
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors();
        return tomcat;
    }
```

Hope this provides some pointer.